# RTAB-map double walls

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just keep getting double walls in rtabmap when using it on my robot.
I am using a Kinect to map the building.
Settings:
http://pastebin.com/CDtTe0JV

The result:

[image description http://i64.tinypic.com/33vojdz.png](http://i64.tinypic.com/33vojdz.png)

EDIT in response to matlabbe:
My odometry source is from the create_autonomy using the roomba 780. I know it has a reasonable drift.
The launchfile I am using is RGBD_mapping.launch
http://pastebin.com/q6B3S6HD

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250537/rtab-map-double-walls/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-12-22**:
What is your odometry source? and which launch file are your using (copy/paste stuff related to rtabmap here)?

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-12-23**:
Edited the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

if the laser scans are fake laser scans from Kinect, I don't recommend using them for ICP refining (causing more errors as they are not very precise with small FOV). Set `--Reg/Strategy 0 --RGBD/NeighborLinkRefining false` in `rtabmap_args`. I see some jumps in odometry. What happens if you disable loop closure detection by adding this `--Kp/MaxFeatures -1` to `rtabmap_args`? The odometry should be smooth, if there are still jumps, there is a problem with odometry. Otherwise it may because of loop closure detection. Try with `--Vis/MaxDepth 3.5` to limit the distance of features used for loop closure transformation (features over 4 meters are very noisy with Kinect v1).

**EDIT**

For loop closure, you can also try increasing `--Vis/MinInliers 30` or re-extract features when computing the transformation `--RGBD/LoopClosureReextractFeatures true`, you may also want to disable `--RGBD/ProximityBySpace false` to avoid adding constraints with the fake laser scans.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-05**:
I changed the parameters you said and did not really see an improvement. For some reason it saw a loop closure at the wrong time ruining the whole scan. Then I disabled loop closures and actually it worked quite well. Except for the fact that my odometry is really bad.

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2017-01-05**:
I will improve the odometry of my robot and show you the results / improvements when done.